# Choosing the best option from the list

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to simulate a model in Modelica and then choose the best option from some list of options, according to simulation results.
For example I have simulated a model and I have a list of possibilities from which I would like to choose the the optimal option from the list.
What are my options? Is there a way to do this with Modelica records or is there some alternative way that I am not aware of?

Comment: What do you mean with option? It's hard to understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: For example I have a list with three available cable diameters, lets say 5, 8 and 12. I simulated my model and the simulated diameter is 11 so therefore I would like to choose cable with diameter 12 from my cable list. Hope, it's more clear now.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Just print it?

Comment: Yeah, just printing would be ok.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your input I would use a vector with available diameters and functions which compute the closest / next bigger / smaller value.

The result can be printed at simulation end in a `when terminal()` statement or you store it in a variable and plot it. I went for the first approach.

```
model DiameterSelection
  import Modelica.Utilities.Streams.{print, error};
  import Modelica.Units.SI;
  import Modelica.Math.Vectors.sort;

  parameter SI.Diameter diameters[:] = {5, 8, 12};
  SI.Diameter d = 11;

protected 
  function findValue "Local function to find next larger or smaller value in a vector."
    input Real x;
    input Real possibilites[:];
    input Boolean larger=true "true: Find closest value which is larger or equal. false: Find closest value which is smaller or equal.";
    output Real y;
  protected 
    Real sorted_possibilites[:];
  algorithm 
    sorted_possibilites := sort(possibilites, ascending=larger);
    for item in sorted_possibilites loop
      if larger and item >=x or not larger and item<=x then
        y :=item;
        return;
      end if;
    end for;
    error("Found no value");
  end findValue;

  function findClosest "Local function to find closest value in a vector."
    input Real value;
    input Real possibilites[:];
    output Real closest;
  protected 
    Real larger, smaller;
  algorithm 
    larger :=findValue(value, possibilites, larger=true);
    smaller :=findValue(value, possibilites, larger=false);
    closest :=if abs(value - larger) < abs(value - smaller) then larger else smaller;
  end findClosest;

equation 
  when terminal() then
    print("Computed diameter: " + String(d) +
          "\nNext smaller diameter: " + String(findValue(d, diameters, larger=false)) + 
          "\nNext bigger diameter: " + String(findValue(d, diameters, larger=true)) + 
          "\nClosest diameter: " + String(findClosest(d, diameters)));
  end when;
end DiameterSelection;
```

Simulate the model and check the simulation output:

[image: simulation output in OpenModelica]